# Can't deploy to a private chain using Truffle

Tags: contract-deployment, private-blockchain, parity, truffle-migration

I created a private Parity chain using the official tutorial (https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial). Then I set it in my Truffle config:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    private: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8540,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

I can connect to it using Truffle console, but when I try to deploy, it hangs forever:

> truffle(private)> migrate --reset
>
> Using network 'private'.
>
> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
>
> Deploying Migrations...

Here's what I see in the node's output:

```
7decca6e11722f25d1b633502f41ff986492b22638c27c8df5eac7e282541738880608081d5cb2d8
91cf0b9e9dc0a42867bfe68da161877ee4eb6e014@127.0.0.1:30300
2018-07-01 19:30:20   TRACE rpc  Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":25,"method":"eth
_accounts","params":[]}.
2018-07-01 19:30:20   DEBUG rpc  Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":["0x00bd138
abd70e2f00903268f3db08f2d25677c9e"],"id":25}.
2018-07-01 19:30:20   TRACE rpc  Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":26,"method":"net
_version","params":[]}.
2018-07-01 19:30:20   DEBUG rpc  Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"8995","id"
:26}.
2018-07-01 19:30:20   TRACE rpc  Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":27,"method":"net
_version","params":[]}.
2018-07-01 19:30:20   DEBUG rpc  Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"8995","id"
:27}.
2018-07-01 19:30:20   TRACE rpc  Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":28,"method":"eth
_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0x00bd138abd70e2f00903268f3db08f2d25677c9e"
,"gas":"0x6691b7","gasPrice":"0x174876e800","data":"0x60806040523480156100105760
0080fd5b50336000806101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916
908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1602179055506102f88061006060003960
00f300608060405260043610610062576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680630900f01014610067578063445df0ac146100aa5780
638da5cb5b146100d5578063fdacd5761461012c575b600080fd5b34801561007357600080fd5b50
6100a8600480360381019080803573ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1690602001
90929190505050610159565b005b3480156100b657600080fd5b506100bf610241565b6040518082
815260200191505060405180910390f35b3480156100e157600080fd5b506100ea610247565b6040
51808273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffff16815260200191505060405180910390f35b34801561013857600080fd5b50610157
6004803603810190808035906020019092919050505061026c565b005b6000806000905490610100
0a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffff163373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16141561023d5781905080
73ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1663fdacd5766001546040518263ffffffff16
7c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002815260040180828152
602001915050600060405180830381600087803b15801561022457600080fd5b505af11580156102
38573d6000803e3d6000fd5b505050505b5050565b60015481565b6000809054906101000a900473
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1681565b6000809054906101000a900473ffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16
3373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1614156102c957806001819055505b505600
a165627a7a72305820f447dde0ef1d4d3a1752d10ae91ef75165287db6411fe180a975e1e0543517
ca0029"}]}.
2018-07-01 19:30:25  Verifier #6 INFO import  Imported #37 5c74:10ce (0 txs, 0.0
0 Mgas, 0.87 ms, 0.56 KiB)
2018-07-01 19:30:27  IO Worker #3 INFO import     1/25 peers     14 KiB chain
20 KiB db  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,  51 чs
2018-07-01 19:30:57  IO Worker #3 INFO import     1/25 peers     14 KiB chain
20 KiB db  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,  51 чs
```

So, as you see, the Request is never getting a Response.

**UPDATE:** the same result happens whenever I just send a simple transaction: it's stuck forever.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it. I needed to unlock my account, the one from which I was deploying. For some reason, Parity didn't tell me about it, so I spent 2 hours guessing.

I unlocked my account using the --unlock commandline option.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say like that. Here is things I'd try:

Verify if it is a firewall issue. - Ping the port you are running

Verify it is not a Parity issue. - Try geth

Verify it is not Truffle issue. Try etherlime to deploy your contracts. Here is a quick snippet:

```
const etherlime = require('etherlime');

const ICOTokenContract = require('./build/contracts/ICOToken.json');

const defaultConfigs = {
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 4700000
}

const deployer = new etherlime.InfuraPrivateKeyDeployer('Your Private KEY', 'ropsten', 'Your infura API key', defaultConfigs);
const contractWrapper = await deployer.deploy(ICOTokenContract); // Make sure you call this method in an async function or use it as a promise without await
```

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/LimeChain/etherlime)